# RoR equivalent of requiring a file in php?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

What's the equivilent of requiring a page in php.. e.g if I broke up a web page into 4 pages `news.php header.php footer.php` and `sidebar.php` which composed my homepage, I'd simply `require` them all to render them on a single page. How would I do this with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

If your talking about doing this in templates.

Comment: Ror is a Framework and PHP is a programming language, so it's hard to directly compare them. Thus I'm not sure exactly what you mean but maybe that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I will point out is that you are probably going down the wrong path. The old PHP method if breaking your layouts into header/footer includes and including them is replaced with a much more powerful layout system in Rails. This setup allows you to save content into buffers ([yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield), [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for)) which can be poked into a single layout file. This method is significantly cleaner and the "proper" way.

Additionally it would probably be good to just generally read the [layouts and rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
require "filename_without_rb_extension"
```